# Javascript: Make colors in an image into links?

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, colors, hyperlink

Basically, there's a color-coded map with 5 different regions on it. They're all oblong, discontinuous, and would take forever to make an image map for. I'm wondering if there's a way to make the colors click-able instead of making a ridiculous image map. Separating the colors into separate images or other similar trickery wouldn't be an issue if it lead to a solution.

Also, I'd upload the image, but it's 2.1MB

Comment: My only suggestion would be to see if you can get the image in svg format and use some canvas/svg trickery...

Comment: Just like jondavidjohn said. You can also try the very good SVG library http://raphaeljs.com/ Let me just note that the thing you are trying to do won't be easy at all.

Comment: Is there anyway I could have javascript (or anything) get the color of each pixel? I could make JS or PHP figure out the shapes and make the image map for me... SVG's look like updated image maps by the way.

Comment: If you could find a way to share a sample image, that would be tremendously helpful to both you and the answerers. Can you try posting it on a public image/file sharing site? Using the shared folder ability of Dropbox would be a safe bet.

Comment: Sure. Here's the link of a scaled version (25% by 25% of the original).  http://www.filedump.net/index.php?pic=denaliecoregionmap25per1332009435.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering the image into a `<canvas>`. Add a click handler to the canvas, and read the color value at the clicked pixel. If you know which color corresponds to which logical region, you got yourself a solution.

In case the image does not have pure solid colors, you might have to get the average in a small region around the clicked pixel.

Comment: As far as I know this solution won't work under IE (getting data from Canvas not implemented). The alternative might be sending mouse coordinates via AJAX and let server handle this.

Comment: Canvas might be a good idea. If I was to use the mouse co-ordinates, I might as well make an image map. I'll have to run this by my boss and see what the best action would be.